# How do i convert flv to mp4/mkv?

Tags: ffmpeg, homebrew, youtube-dl

I'm trying to grab content from http://tv.nrk.no and the content is downloaded as *.flv. But VLC cannot play that file, no errors or other information.

I have tried to reinstall ffmpeg with additional codes: `brew reinstall ffmpeg --with-libvpx` and convert the flv file to mp4. But getting error `*.flv: could not find codec parameters`.

So how can I either download in another format? Or convert the file to mkv/mp4?

Comment: Please use the [homebrew] tag instead of [brew], which has nothing to do with that. I edited your question to fix the tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot download the content, so I can't try the input video from http://tv.nrk.no

And, what is your command line? Can you post it?
It seems that you don't have some codec.

Maybe you can download ffmpeg-static to transcode the video.

Comment: First I use `youtube-dl` and all available versions is flv. So I choose the "best" quality. Then when trying to convert I use ffmpeg `ffmpeg -I Filem.flv -vcodec copy -acodec copy Film.mp4`. Gives me errors :/

Comment: Also, I cannot download the video because the program can not be displayed abroad.

Comment: Yes I have tried other, same result. Even tried the app Handbrake on macos

Comment: Do you want to try to re-encode? 
ffmpeg -i test.flv -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -a:v copy test.mp4